# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo. java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=7; index=7

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent, android-activity

```
public class Drawing_Activity extends Activity{

ViewPager viewpager;
TextView txtstep;
ImageView imageView;
Button btnback,btnnext;
RelativeLayout reldraw;
ImageView imgcolorpick,imgpencil,imgstroke,imgeraser,imgclearr,imgsave;
private static int TOTAL_IMAGES;
private int currentPosition = 0;
protected Dialog dialog;
protected View layout;
protected int progress;
protected float stroke = 6;
private String fileName;
PaintView pv;
int count=0;
String get1;
private AdView mAdView;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.drawing_activity);

    mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    mAdView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

    btnback=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_prev);
    btnnext=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_next);
    reldraw=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rell);
    viewpager=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.view_pagercake);
    txtstep=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_stepsize);

    Intent i=getIntent();
    get1=i.getExtras().getString("Image_Array");
    //Log.e("get1---", get1);

    imgcolorpick=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2_color);
    imgstroke=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView4_stroke);
    imgclearr=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView5_clear);
    imgeraser=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView3_eraser);
    imgpencil=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1_pencil);
    imgsave=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1_save);

    imgpencil.setImageResource(R.drawable.brush_active_btn); //click of pencil

    this.pv = new PaintView(this);
    this.pv.togglePencil(true);
    reldraw .addView(pv);

    imgcolorpick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            showColorPickerDialogDemo();
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hiiii", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    imgstroke.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            strokeDialog();
        }
    });

    imgclearr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Drawing_Activity.this.pv.clear();
        }
    });

    imgeraser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Drawing_Activity.this.pv.togglePencil(false);
            imgeraser.setImageResource(R.drawable.erase_active_btn);
            imgpencil.setImageResource(R.drawable.brush_btn);
        }
    });

    imgpencil.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Drawing_Activity.this.pv.togglePencil(true);
            imgpencil.setImageResource(R.drawable.brush_active_btn);
            imgeraser.setImageResource(R.drawable.erase_btn);
        }
    });
    imgsave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Drawing_Activity.this.save();
        }
    });

    viewpager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            txtstep.setText(String.valueOf(arg0)+"/"+TOTAL_IMAGES);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

    ImagePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter();
    viewpager.setAdapter(adapter);
    if(get1.equals("image_car"))
    {
        TOTAL_IMAGES = (Image_Arrays.image_car.length - 1);
    }
    else if(get1.equals("image_house"))
    {
        TOTAL_IMAGES = (Image_Arrays.image_house.length - 1);
    }
    else if(get1.equals("image_horse"))
    {
        TOTAL_IMAGES = (Image_Arrays.image_horse.length - 1);
    }
    else if(get1.equals("image_bird"))
    {
        TOTAL_IMAGES = (Image_Arrays.image_bird.length - 1);
    }
    else if(get1.equals("image_elephant"))
    {
        TOTAL_IMAGES = (Image_Arrays.image_elephant.length - 1);
    }
    else if(get1.equals("image_shoes"))
    {
        TOTAL_IMAGES = (Image_Arrays.image_shoes.length - 1);
    }
    else if(get1.equals("image_bottle"))
    {
        TOTAL_IMAGES = (Image_Arrays.image_bottle.length - 1);

    }
    else
    {
        TOTAL_IMAGES = (Image_Arrays.image_car.length - 1);
    }
    txtstep.setText(String.valueOf(0)+"/"+TOTAL_IMAGES);
    btnback.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            currentPosition = viewpager.getCurrentItem();

            int positionToMoveTo = currentPosition;
            positionToMoveTo--;
            if (positionToMoveTo < 0) {
                positionToMoveTo = TOTAL_IMAGES;
            }
            viewpager.setCurrentItem(positionToMoveTo);
        }
    });
    btnnext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            currentPosition = viewpager.getCurrentItem();

            int positionToMoveTo = currentPosition;
            positionToMoveTo++;
            if (currentPosition == TOTAL_IMAGES) {
                positionToMoveTo = 0;
            }
            viewpager.setCurrentItem(positionToMoveTo);

        }
    });

}
protected int getItem(int i) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}
private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if(get1.equals("image_car"))
        {
            return Image_Arrays.image_car.length;
        }
        else if(get1.equals("image_house"))
        {
            return Image_Arrays.image_house.length;
        }
        else if(get1.equals("image_horse"))
        {
            return Image_Arrays.image_horse.length;
        }
        else if(get1.equals("image_bird"))
        {
            return Image_Arrays.image_bird.length;
        }
        else if(get1.equals("image_elephant"))
        {
            return Image_Arrays.image_elephant.length;
        }
        else if(get1.equals("image_shoes"))
        {
            return Image_Arrays.image_shoes.length;
        }
        else if(get1.equals("image_bottle"))
        {
            return Image_Arrays.image_bottle.length;

        }
        else
        {
            return Image_Arrays.image_car.length;

        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((ImageView) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        Context context = Drawing_Activity.this;

        imageView = new ImageView(context);

        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);

        if(get1.equals("image_car"))
        {
            imageView.setImageResource(Image_Arrays.image_car[position]);
        }
        else if(get1.equals("image_house"))
        {
            imageView.setImageResource(Image_Arrays.image_house[position]);
        }
        else if(get1.equals("image_horse"))
        {
            imageView.setImageResource(Image_Arrays.image_horse[position]);
        }
        else if(get1.equals("image_bird"))
        {
            imageView.setImageResource(Image_Arrays.image_bird[position]);
        }
        else if(get1.equals("image_elephant"))
        {
            imageView.setImageResource(Image_Arrays.image_elephant[position]);
        }
        else if(get1.equals("image_shoes"))
        {
            imageView.setImageResource(Image_Arrays.image_shoes[position]);
        }
        else if(get1.equals("image_bottle"))
        {
            imageView.setImageResource(Image_Arrays.image_bottle[position]);

        }
        else
        {
            imageView.setImageResource(Image_Arrays.image_car[position]);
        }

        ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);

        return imageView;

    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
    }
}

private void showColorPickerDialogDemo() {

    int initialColor = Color.WHITE;

    ColorPickerDialog colorPickerDialog = new ColorPickerDialog(this, initialColor, new OnColorSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onColorSelected(int color) {

            Drawing_Activity.this.pv.setColor(color);
        }

    });
    colorPickerDialog.show();
}

private class PaintView extends View {

    private Paint paint;
    private Bitmap bmp;
    private Paint bmpPaint;
    private Canvas canvas;
    private Context context;
    private float mX, mY;
    private Path path;
    private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 0.8f;
    private int colour;
    private Bitmap bgImage; // image that gets loaded
    protected Boolean pencil;

    private PaintView(Context c) {
        super(c);

        setDrawingCacheEnabled(true); // to save images

        this.context = c;
        this.colour = Color.BLACK;
        this.path = new Path();
        this.bmpPaint = new Paint();
        this.paint = new Paint();
        this.paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        this.paint.setDither(true);
        this.paint.setColor(this.colour);
        this.paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        this.paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        this.paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        this.paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        this.bgImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        this.bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        this.canvas = new Canvas(this.bmp);
        bgImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.inner_bg).copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

    }

    private void touchStart(float x, float y) {
        this.path.reset();
        this.path.moveTo(x, y);
        this.mX = x;
        this.mY = y;
    }

    private void touchUp() {
        this.path.lineTo(mX, mY);
        // commit the path to our offscreen
        this.canvas.drawPath(this.path, paint);
        // kill this so we don't double draw
        this.path.reset();
    }

    private void touchMove(float x, float y) {
        float dx = Math.abs(x - this.mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y - this.mY);
        if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
            // draws a quadratic curve
            this.path.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        float x = e.getX();
        float y = e.getY();

        switch (e.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            this.touchStart(x, y);
            this.touchMove(x + 0.8f, y + 0.8f);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            this.touchMove(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            this.touchUp();

            invalidate();
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    // Called on invalidate();
    @Override
    protected void onDraw (Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        canvas.drawBitmap(this.bgImage, 0, 0, this.bmpPaint);

        canvas.drawBitmap(this.bmp, 0, 0, this.bmpPaint);

        canvas.drawPath(this.path, this.paint);

    }

    /*
     * Menu called methods
     */
    protected void togglePencil(Boolean b) {
        if (b) { // set pencil
            paint.setXfermode(null);
            this.pencil = true;

        } else { // set eraser
            paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
            this.pencil = false;
        }
        //Draw_Dog.this.setTitle();

    }

    public void setColor(int c) {
        this.paint.setColor(c);
        this.colour = c;
    }

    protected int getColor() {
        return this.colour;
    }

    protected void clear() {
        this.path = new Path(); // empty path
        this.canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        if (this.bgImage != null) {
            this.canvas.drawBitmap(this.bgImage, 0, 0, null);
        }
        this.invalidate();
    }
}
public void strokeDialog() {

    this.dialog = new Dialog(this);
    this.dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this
            .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.stroke_dialog,
            (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.dialog_root_element));

    SeekBar dialogSeekBar = (SeekBar) layout
            .findViewById(R.id.dialog_seekbar);

    dialogSeekBar.setThumbOffset(convertDipToPixels(9.5f));
    dialogSeekBar.setProgress((int) this.stroke * 2);

    this.setTextView(this.layout, String.valueOf(Math.round(this.stroke)));

    dialogSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // herp
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // derp
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBark, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {
            Drawing_Activity.this.progress = progress / 2;
            Drawing_Activity.this
            .setTextView(Drawing_Activity.this.layout, "" + Drawing_Activity.this.progress);

            Button b = (Button) Drawing_Activity.this.layout
                    .findViewById(R.id.dialog_button);
            b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Drawing_Activity.this.stroke = Drawing_Activity.this.progress;
                    Drawing_Activity.this.pv.paint.setStrokeWidth(Drawing_Activity.this.stroke);
                    Drawing_Activity.this.dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
        }
    });

    dialog.setContentView(layout);
    dialog.show();
}
protected void setTextView(View layout, String s) {
    TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.stroke_text);
    text.setText(s);
}

private int convertDipToPixels(float dip) {
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    float density = metrics.density;
    return (int) (dip * density);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;

}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{
    switch (item.getItemId()) 
    {

    //  Toast.makeText(this, "Save", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    case R.id.Share:
        reldraw.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        OutputStream fOut = null;
        File file = new File(path,
                "Android/data/com.viavilab.androiddrawing;/cache/share_cache.jpg");
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();

        try {
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Log.e("draw_save", e.toString());
        }

        try {
            fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Log.e("draw_save1", e.toString());
        }

        if (this.reldraw.getDrawingCache() == null) {
            //Log.e("lal", "tis null");
        }

        this.reldraw.getDrawingCache()
        .compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, fOut);

        try {
            fOut.flush();
            fOut.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //Log.e("draw_save1", e.toString());
        }

        Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        share.setType("image/jpeg");
        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://" + file.getAbsolutePath()));

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image"));
        return true;

    case R.id.RateApp:
        final String appName = getPackageName();
        try {
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appName)));
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
            startActivity(new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id="
                            + appName)));
        }
        return true;

    case R.id.About:
        Intent intentabout=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),AboutActivity.class);
        startActivity(intentabout);

    }

    return(super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
}

public void save() { // called on save menu

    reldraw.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    OutputStream fOut = null;
    File file = new File(path,
            getString(R.string.app_name)+"/"+"AD_"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    file.getParentFile().mkdirs();

    try {
        file.createNewFile();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("draw_save", e.toString());
    }

    try {
        fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("draw_save1", e.toString());
    }

    if (this.reldraw.getDrawingCache() == null) {
        Log.e("lal", "tis null");
    }

    this.reldraw.getDrawingCache()
    .compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, fOut);

    try {
        fOut.flush();
        fOut.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("draw_save1", e.toString());
    }
}
```

}

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
    ListView lsvmain;
    ArrayList<List_Item> ListArray = new ArrayList<List_Item>();
    List_Adapter listadapter;
    String[] title,description;
    private InterstitialAd mInterstitial;
    private AdView mAdView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        title= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.names);
        description= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.descriptions);

        lsvmain=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView_main);

        for(int i=0; i<title.length;i++)
        {
            List_Item item=new List_Item(description[i], title[i],Image_Arrays.icons[i]);
            ListArray.add(item);
        }

        listadapter = new List_Adapter(this, R.layout.list_item,ListArray);
        lsvmain.setAdapter(listadapter);

        lsvmain.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if(position==0)
                {
                Intent intentnew=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Drawing_Activity.class);
                intentnew.putExtra("Image_Array", "image_car");
                startActivity(intentnew);
                }
                else if(position==1)
                {
                Intent intentnew=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Drawing_Activity.class);
                intentnew.putExtra("Image_Array", "image_house");
                startActivity(intentnew);
                }
                else if(position==2)
                {
                Intent intentnew=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Drawing_Activity.class);
                intentnew.putExtra("Image_Array", "image_horse");
                startActivity(intentnew);
                }
                else if(position==3)
                {
                Intent intentnew=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Drawing_Activity.class);
                intentnew.putExtra("Image_Array", "image_bird");
                startActivity(intentnew);
                }
                else if(position==4)
                {
                Intent intentnew=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Drawing_Activity.class);
                intentnew.putExtra("Image_Array", "image_elephant");
                startActivity(intentnew);
                }
                else if(position==5)
                {
                Intent intentnew=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Drawing_Activity.class);
                intentnew.putExtra("Image_Array", "image_shoes");
                startActivity(intentnew);
                }
                else if(position==6)
                {
                Intent intentnew=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Drawing_Activity.class);
                intentnew.putExtra("Image_Array", "image_bottle");
                startActivity(intentnew);
                }

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {


        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            // Toast.makeText(appContext, "BAck", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    MainActivity.this);
            alert.setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
            alert.setIcon(R.drawable.app_icon);
            alert.setMessage("Are You Sure You Want To Quit?");

            alert.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                        int whichButton) {

                    if (mInterstitial.isLoaded()) {
                        mInterstitial.show();
                    }
                    finish();
                }
            });

            alert.setNegativeButton("Rate App",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    final String appName = getPackageName();
                    try {
                        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                                Uri.parse("market://details?id="
                                        + appName)));
                    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(
                                Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                                Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id="
                                        + appName)));
                    }
                }
            });
            alert.show();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

> 07-31 10:28:10.311: E/AndroidRuntime(6707): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   07-31 10:28:10.311: E/AndroidRuntime(6707):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.viavilab.androiddrawing/com.viavilab.androiddrawing.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=7; index=7 07-31
>   10:28:10.311: E/AndroidRuntime(6707):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2204)
>   07-31 10:28:10.311: E/AndroidRuntime(6707):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2254)
>   07-31 10:28:10.311: E/AndroidRuntime(6707):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 07-31
>   10:28:10.311: E/AndroidRuntime(6707):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
>   07-31 10:28:10.311: E/AndroidRuntime(6707):   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 07-31
>   10:28:10.311: E/AndroidRuntime(6707):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 07-31 10:28:10.311:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(6707):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5069) 07-31
>   10:28:10.311: E/AndroidRuntime(6707):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 07-31
>   10:28:10.311: E/AndroidRuntime(6707):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 07-31 10:28:10.311:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(6707):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>   07-31 10:28:10.311: E/AndroidRuntime(6707):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 07-31
>   10:28:10.311: E/AndroidRuntime(6707):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 07-31 10:28:10.311:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(6707): Caused by:
>   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=7; index=7 07-31
>   10:28:10.311: E/AndroidRuntime(6707):     at
>   com.viavilab.androiddrawing.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:50)
>   07-31 10:28:10.311: E/AndroidRuntime(6707):   at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104) 07-31
>   10:28:10.311: E/AndroidRuntime(6707):     at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1092)
>   07-31 10:28:10.311: E/AndroidRuntime(6707):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
>   07-31 10:28:10.311: E/AndroidRuntime(6707):   ... 11 more

Comment: The problem solved? There is also a variable "i" of intent. Two variables with same name can lead to mess-up. Worth checking I think.

Comment: Why total images minus 1?

Comment: i did buy the code just like this, but now the developer is not responding. and i'm not that good in java :/

Answer (score 0):

```
com.viavilab.androiddrawing.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:50) 07-31 10:28:10.311:
```

It says your error is in 50th line of method onCreate and the error is that your index is out of the array, check your code please.

Comment: can you show me please, in the question i posted the mainactivity code, can you show me what should i do exactly please ??

Comment: Could you show me what code in exactly 50th line? I don't know whether stackoverflow can show the line number

Comment: I copied your code to my editor and it shows the 50th line is "else if(position = 2)"

Comment: List_Item item=new List_Item(description[i], title[i],Image_Arrays.icons[i]);

Comment: in my editor it shows that the line 50 is : 

List_Item item=new List_Item(description[i], title[i],Image_Arrays.icons[i]);

Comment: so that is because you are trying to access description[7] but your maximum length of description is 6. That is because your title.length is larger than 6.

Comment: how can i solve this problem, and make the meximum length of description more than 6. and thank you so much for your help

Comment: look at the definition -> String[] title,description;      and where is your initialization of the String arrays?

Comment: i did post the drawing activity, can you please look at it ?

Comment: I don't think this is relevant to DrawingActivity  description= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.descriptions); 1. look at your R.array.descriptions. 2.try to print your descriptions array to see the elements, and the size of the array

Comment: oh yes, now i understand, but the problem is that i had array that are more than 7 pictures and the app was working without any problems. but know that i changed the pictures and the arrays names, it crushes??

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
for(int i=0; i<title.length -1 ;i++)
```

in place of your original code. But I need to check how `array.length`  and `array.length -1` really work. :)

I think when it comes to `index` and the `length` of a `array`, `array.length -1` is the solution. But `something.length` in `File InputSteam` or others alike.

And please understand that we `index` an `array` like this:

```
title [] = [ index 0 , index 1, index 2 , ... index ( array.lenth -1) ]
```

Now your code's `index` is 7 and your  `array.length`  is only 7. Where is the value of `index 7`   ? :)

Comment: the problem is the code was working, but once i changed the arrays and the pictures, now once i open it, it crushes. i will post the image_arrays activity

Answer (score 0):

This line is ok, you are getting every item from array:

```
for(int i=0; i<title.length;i++) {
```

The problem comes here:

```
List_Item item=new List_Item(description[i], title[i],Image_Arrays.icons[i]);
```

The array "Image_Arrays" is smaller then array "title" and thats throws exception. You can test there lengths:

```
Log.d("ArrayLength", "title: " + String.valueOf(title.length) + " icons: "+ String.valueOf(Image_Arrays.icons.length))
```

Comment: thank you all for your answers, this is by far the best website for android. i solved the problem. thank you again